# how to plot multiple line in matplotlib with every line have different number of values than the other

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot, graph

i want to plot 6 line in the same graph using matplot lib but it keep show me this error

```
raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (2,)
```

afret i search about it it look that i have to make all the line in the graph with the same number of value

is there a way to make it happend with different number of values than the other

or a way to make the missed value a 0

this is my code

```
def graph_dep_type_all_2 (self): # pushButton_159
        ''' my table 
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  depances (
            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
            type VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            nom VARCHAR,
            montant DECIMAL(100,2) NOT NULL,
            date DATE,
            temp TIME)'''
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                            password="password",
                                            host="localhost",
                                            database="database")
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()

        date_0 = str(self.dateEdit_72.text())
        date_1 = str(self.dateEdit_71.text()) 
        types_1 = str('salaire des médecins')

        selected_day = self.dateEdit_72.date()
        last_day = selected_day.addDays(-1)
        last_day_str = last_day.toString(self.dateEdit_72.displayFormat())

        self.cur.execute( '''SELECT date, SUM(montant) FROM depances WHERE type=%s AND (date + temp) > (%s::date + '16:00:00'::time) AND (date + temp) < (%s::date + '16:00:00'::time) GROUP BY (date)'''
                            ,(types_1, last_day_str, date_1))
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()

        date = []
        montant_s_m = []
        moyenne_s_m = []

        date_s_e = []
        montant_s_e = []
        moyenne_s_e = []

        date_a_d = []
        montant_a_d = []
        moyenne_a_d = []


        for row in rows:
            date.append(row[0])
            montant_s_m.append(row[1])

        avg = sum(montant_s_m)/len(date)
        for avgs in enumerate(date):
            moyenne_s_m.append(avg)
        
        ################################### salaire des employe 

        types_2 = str('salaire des employe')
        
        self.cur.execute( '''SELECT date, SUM(montant) FROM depances WHERE type=%s AND (date + temp) > (%s::date + '16:00:00'::time) AND (date + temp) < (%s::date + '16:00:00'::time) GROUP BY (date)'''
                            ,(types_2, last_day_str, date_1))
        rows_2 = self.cur.fetchall()

        for row in rows_2:
            date_s_e.append(row[0])
            montant_s_e.append(row[1])

        avg_2 = sum(montant_s_e)/len(date_s_e)
        for avgs in enumerate(date):
            moyenne_s_e.append(avg_2)

        ################################### autre dépenses 
        montant_a_d = []
        moyenne_a_d = []

        types_3 = str('autre dépenses')
        
        self.cur.execute( '''SELECT date, SUM(montant) FROM depances WHERE type=%s AND (date + temp) > (%s::date + '16:00:00'::time) AND (date + temp) < (%s::date + '16:00:00'::time) GROUP BY (date)'''
                            ,(types_3, last_day_str, date_1))
        rows_3 = self.cur.fetchall()

        for row in rows_3:
            date_a_d.append(row[0])
            montant_a_d.append(row[1])

        avg_3 = sum(montant_a_d)/len(date_a_d)
        for avgs in enumerate(date):
            moyenne_a_d.append(avg_3)
        

        figure,ax=plt.subplots()
         
        ax.set_xlabel("date(jour)")
        ax.set_ylabel("montant (DZD)")
        line1, = plt.plot(date, montant_s_m, marker="o", label="salaire des médecins")
        line2, = plt.plot(date, moyenne_s_m, marker= "x", label="la moyenne des salaires des médecins")

        line3, = plt.plot(date_s_e, montant_s_e, marker="s", label="salaire des employe")
        line4, = plt.plot(date_s_e, moyenne_s_e, marker= "p", label="la moyenne des salaires des employe")

        line5, = plt.plot(date_a_d, montant_s_m, marker="*", label="autre dépenses")
        line6, = plt.plot(date_a_d, moyenne_a_d, marker= "h", label="la moyenne des autres dépenses")
        plt.legend(handles=[line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6])
        plt.show(block=False)
```

Comment: You give it 1 x-coordinate and 2 y-coordinates. It says it can't plot.

Comment: yes i have 6 x coordinate, i try it with 2 coordinate it work perfectly but like this i dont know why

Comment: Each point has 1 x-coordinate and 1 y-coordinate. You need to give it the same number of x-coordinate and y-coordinate. If you give it 5 x-coordinates and 7 y-coordinates, it can't figure out what does the 2 extra y-coordinates do. Since we can't run your program, we can't figure this out for you. Try to make a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that we can run.